# OnClickListener Does not Respond to Clicks in Fragment

Tags: android, tabs, onclick, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am transferring an old program over to a Tabs and Fragments implementation. The user inputs an Id for a search and then hits Submit. However my "Submit Button" does nothing.

I have tried several alternative coding variants but get same result - dead air!

Here is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/setUpAthletesTab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background="#CCFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/instructionText"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextAthlete0"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/hintText"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAthleteName0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/athleteHintName0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
```

Here is my Tab / Fragment

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* Begin Insertion */
        LayoutInflater myInflater = inflater;
        ViewGroup myContainer = container;
        if(inflater == null) myInflater = inflater;
        if(container == null) myContainer = container;
        Log.d(APP_TAG,"At line 50 of Tab3Fragment myInflater = " + myInflater + " and myContainer = " + myContainer);
        getAthleteInfoFromExistingDatabase(myInflater,myContainer);

        LinearLayout tab3LinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag3_layout, container, false);

        View mySubmitButton = tab3LinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        ((Button) mySubmitButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(Tab3Fragment.this.getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        "clicked on Submit Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), RetrieveAthleteData.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag3_layout, container, false);
    }
```

Neither the Toast box nor the Intent fire off when I hit submit.

Thanks for looking at my question.

**Problem solved!** Thanks Dirk for suggesting name change to all lower case.

Comment: I assume you can see the log message emitted by: "Log.d(APP_TAG..."? And there is no NullpointerException on setOnClickListener()? To test something: can you put the Toast before the line with the findViewById(). Is it showing up then?

Comment: Yes, I can see the Log.d statement. I inserted Toast statements immediately before and after the declaration of mySubmitButton. Both of those appear.

It seems like I missed something basic in the declarations of my XML file. Am investigating that right now.

Comment: In your xml is no Button with the id "submitButton". You should only use lowercase and therefore give it the id "@+id/submit_button".

Comment: OTOH you should get a NullPointerException or ClassCastException if there were no Button with that id. I'd guess you are loading another layout than you think and therefore hit another button that has no onClickListener registered.

Comment: Okay, I took Dirk's suggestion and renamed my button, so that it had no capital letters to "submit_button". That did the trick! I now can see the Toast Message whenever I hit the button. (The button was defined in my XML, I just mistakenly omitted that from my post - dumb newbie!) 

Not sure why that matters, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Since you found the solution yourself: Please add it as an answer and accept it, so the questions does not show up as unanswered anymore. If you want me to, I can add my tip as an answer.

Comment: Dirk would be more honest to add your tip as Answer then I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml is no Button with the id "submitButton".

You should only use lowercase and therefore give it the id "@+id/submit_button"

Although I could not find a source that camel case ids are not allowed. Even Google uses camel case ids in their examples sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You're inflating and returning a brand spanking new set of views here:

```
return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag3_layout, container, false);
```

you should be returning the inflated view's that you acted upon:

```
return tab3LinearLayout;
```